# Opencart Gzip doesnt work

Tags: compression, gzip, opencart, deflate

I couldnt find the solution everything is ok on the server and htacess file.
But on my xxxxx.com doest work gzip.But xxxxx.com/admin gzip working.
I need to activate to gzip to my homepage because website loading time is about 9sec.

Anyone can help me  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to set the compression level in admin settings 
http://xxxxxx.com/admin/index.php?route=setting/setting ?
Put there a value from 0 to 9 (for example 6).

Comment: i already tried that there is somethings else.because admin page gzip working but main page doesnt.maybe there is a problem with js files. so i couldnt find the error.